# How to find count of elements by class and calculate on hover?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

Here is my code:

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onmouseover = (event) => {
    document.querySelector(`#result`).innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll(`#wrapper .innerElemType${i+1}`).length
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 10rem;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#btn {
  width: 10rem;
}

#result {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="Type1">
    <div class="Type1-1">
      <div class="Type1-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type1-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type1-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type1-1">
      <div class="Type1-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type1-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Type2">
    <div class="Type2-1">
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type2-1">
      <div class="Type2-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Type3">
    <div class="Type3-1">
      <div class="Type3-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type3-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type3-1">
      <div class="Type3-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type3-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type3-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Type4">
    <div class="Type4-1">
      <div class="Type4-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type4-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type4-1">
      <div class="Type4-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type4-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button id="Type1">Type1</button>
  <button id="Type2">Type2</button>
  <button id="Type3">Type3</button>
  <button id="Type4">Type3</button>
  <button id="Type1-1">Type1-1</button>
  <button id="Type2-1">Type2-1</button>
  <button id="Type3-1">Type3-1</button>
  <button id="Type4-1">Type4-1</button>
  <button id="Type1-1-1">Type1-1-1</button>
  <button id="Type2-1-1">Type2-1-1</button>
  <button id="Type3-1-1">Type3-1-1</button>
  <button id="Type4-1-1">Type4-1-1</button>
</div>


<div id="result">Type1 Result</div>
```

i have a tree, main div's have classes Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4. in main div's we have sub classes and in sub classes we have sub sub classes.

how to get count of same class elements by hovering on relevant buttons? need javascript help.

https://jsfiddle.net/739bL1a4/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the `id` from your button and include it in your `.querySelectorAll`

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].onmouseover = (event) => {
    document.querySelector(`#result`).innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll(`#wrapper .${event.target.id}`).length
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 10rem;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#btn {
  width: 10rem;
}

#result {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="Type1">
    <div class="Type1-1">
      <div class="Type1-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type1-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type1-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type1-1">
      <div class="Type1-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type1-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Type2">
    <div class="Type2-1">
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type2-1">
      <div class="Type2-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type2-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Type3">
    <div class="Type3-1">
      <div class="Type3-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type3-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type3-1">
      <div class="Type3-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type3-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type3-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Type4">
    <div class="Type4-1">
      <div class="Type4-1-1"></div>
      <div class="Type4-1-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Type4-1">
      <div class="Type4-1-2"></div>
      <div class="Type4-1-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <button id="Type1">Type1</button>
  <button id="Type2">Type2</button>
  <button id="Type3">Type3</button>
  <button id="Type4">Type3</button>
  <button id="Type1-1">Type1-1</button>
  <button id="Type2-1">Type2-1</button>
  <button id="Type3-1">Type3-1</button>
  <button id="Type4-1">Type4-1</button>
  <button id="Type1-1-1">Type1-1-1</button>
  <button id="Type2-1-1">Type2-1-1</button>
  <button id="Type3-1-1">Type3-1-1</button>
  <button id="Type4-1-1">Type4-1-1</button>
</div>


<div id="result">Type1 Result</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to get "type1-1" div's count, when i hover at type1 button?

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll(\`#wrapper .${event.target.id}\`).children`

Comment: Oh sorry, `document.querySelectorAll` will return a nodelist, you will need to loop over it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change your CSS selector to look for div(s) inside wrapper whose class attribute matches to that of the button you're hovering.

```
`#wrapper div[class="${btns[i].innerText}"]`
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

btns.forEach(btn => {
 btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    const totalNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.' + btn.textContent).length;
   resultDiv.textContent = totalNumber;
 }); 
});
```